# Send data from a Javafx-Client over Websockets to EventBus

Tags: javafx, websocket, event-bus, vert.x

I have a Socket handler in *Vert.x* and I know how to send data through the EventBus in a client-to-server (from Web Browser to Web Server) and server-component-to-server-component fashions.

Now I have a JavaFX-Client connected to the *Vert.x* Socket handler through websockets:

```
public void start() {

    vertx.createHttpClient()
    .setHost(Main.SOCKET_SERVER)
    .setPort(8080)
    .connectWebsocket("/chat/service", new Handler<WebSocket>() {                   
        @Override
        public void handle(WebSocket websocket) {
            ws = websocket;  
            websocket.dataHandler(new Handler<Buffer>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(Buffer data) {
                    System.out.println("Received Data");
                }
            });

            //...
            // use ws for authentification
            ws.writeTextFrame("doAuthentification");
            //...
        }    
    }
}
```

The Socket is connected to "/chat/service".

Now I want to use this Websocket to call different Services from *Vert.x*. I know that EventBus is not working from JavaFX-Client.

On the server:

```
ws.dataHandler(new Handler<Buffer>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(final Buffer data) {
        String text = data.toString();          
        if(text.contentEquals("doAuthentification")){
            logger.info("doAuthentification()");
            doAuthentification();
        }
    // ...
    }
}
```

I can now send "commands" like **doAuthentification** through the WebSocket, then, on server side and when that command is received, I can use the EventBus to process it further.

What would be the correct way using it from a client. Ideas?

Comment: Is the *JavaFX* client deployed as a `verticle` or as a standalone application?

Comment: Hi. Its a standalone application. Not running as verticle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you application is packaged as a standalone application is not deployed as in a *Vert.x* instance, you won't be able to call the event-bus since it is a *Vert.x* specific feature.

Your method to go would be, as you already tyried, to communicate to your *Vert.x* application in a standard way, through socket, or http for example (I would recommend HTTP and a RESTful application style), and send messages through an entry point that will be later on transferred to the appropriate verticles.

You may need to configure many path based handlers, maybe using a regex capture group inside, and let each handler choose the appropriate schema to delegate events, instead of having a single handler based on hardcoded messages.